# Pandas rolling apply: pass in a two-dimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I wish to perform some rolling calculations on. This is not a simple formula so there's nothing built in. For purposes of a minimal verifiable complete example, let us assume that the dataframe is.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 6.1, 8.1],
                   'b': [2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 7.2, 9.2]})
```

to which I am applying the following (again simplified for debugging and illustrative purposes).

```
def func(arr):
    print(arr)
    return 0
```

The print(arr) is to see what is being fed in. So the requirement is I wish to take a rolling window of size 4 of both column a and b at the same time. So the array dimensions should be 4 x 2.

I tried

```
df_res = df.rolling(window=4, center=False).apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

The print(arr) gives

```
[ 1.1  2.1  3.1  4.1]
[ 2.1  3.1  4.1  6.1]
[ 3.1  4.1  6.1  8.1]
[ 2.2  3.2  4.2  5.2]
[ 3.2  4.2  5.2  7.2]
[ 4.2  5.2  7.2  9.2]
```

and df_res gives

```
     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0
```

which is just feeding a 4 x 1 array for column a and b separately.

According to this StackOverflow answer, [apply a function on rolling window in Dataframe where whole dataframe is passed to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420909/apply-a-function-on-rolling-window-in-dataframe-where-whole-dataframe-is-passed), the suggestion is to use min_periods and axis=1.

```
df_res = df.rolling(window=4, min_periods=2, axis=1, center=False).apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

But this too is not what I require. The print(arr) gives.

```
[ 1.1  2.2]
[ 2.1  3.2]
[ 3.1  4.2]
[ 4.1  5.2]
[ 6.1  7.2]
[ 8.1  9.2]
```

and the df_res is of the form

```
    a    b
0 NaN  0.0
1 NaN  0.0
2 NaN  0.0
3 NaN  0.0
4 NaN  0.0
5 NaN  0.0
```

So what happened is that it is feeding in a 2 x 1 array. How can I get pandas to do a rolling window size of 4 and across both columns so that what gets fed in is a 4 x 2 array?

Answer (score 1):

Since `Pandas` version `1.3.0` you can use the `method` argument:

From the docs:

> method : str {'single', 'table'}, default 'single'
>
> .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
>
> Execute the rolling operation per single column or row (`'single'`)
> or over the entire object (`'table'`).
>
> This argument is only implemented when specifying `engine='numba'`
> in the method call.

So first you have to install `numba` with:

```
pip install numba
```

Now you can do this:

```
rw = df.rolling(window = 4, method = "table")
df_res = rw.apply(func, engine = "numba", raw = True)

[[1.1 2.2]]
[[1.1 2.2] 
 [2.1 3.2]]
[[1.1 2.2] 
 [2.1 3.2] 
 [3.1 4.2]]
[[1.1 2.2] 
 [2.1 3.2] 
 [3.1 4.2] 
 [4.1 5.2]]
[[2.1 3.2] 
 [3.1 4.2] 
 [4.1 5.2] 
 [6.1 7.2]]
[[3.1 4.2] 
 [4.1 5.2] 
 [6.1 7.2] 
 [8.1 9.2]]

df_res

     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0
```

Notice that the first three iterations, the function inputs are not of the correct size, so you will have to take care of those specific cases. Sadly, this cannot be solved setting `min_periods = 8` or you get the following error:

```
ValueError: min_periods 8 must be <= window 4
```

---

Another this you can do is using `numpy` to get the rolling window with [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

rw = sliding_window_view(df, (4,2))

rw

array([[[[1.1, 2.2],
         [2.1, 3.2],
         [3.1, 4.2],
         [4.1, 5.2]]],


       [[[2.1, 3.2],
         [3.1, 4.2],
         [4.1, 5.2],
         [6.1, 7.2]]],


       [[[3.1, 4.2],
         [4.1, 5.2],
         [6.1, 7.2],
         [8.1, 9.2]]]])
```

As you can see, every position is a occurrence of the rolling window.

From this point you should use `numpy` to get the values that `func` returns.

---

Done with `pandas` version `2.0.1`.